# Adblocker Blocks an Important Piece of My Application

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm trying to break sections of my legacy ASP.NET MVC App into small micro frontends and I'm leveraging custom HTML elements to do that.

The problem is that whenever I try to import the Javascript for these micro frontends from my main app

```
<script src="http://localhost:9001/app.js">
</script>
```

I get blocked by my Adblocker. (I'm using Brave browser)

[image]

I understand that I can unblock it in my browser but it would be unreasonable to ask a customer to do so.

How can I avoid something like that in production?

Comment: I don't think this should be blocked by an adblocker. The problem is that there is no single "rule" for how an adblocker behaves. Or there actually *is* but it's not useful - adblockers work on *lists* of rules that define what should be blocked and what shouldn't be. The actual blocking mechanism boils down to applying these rules to any resource a site tries to take. `localhost` is *usually* not included but depends on what filter rules are enabled.

Comment: @VLAZ I was surprised as well that it would block a localhost import... in production the import path would probably be a subdomain of the main app, do you know if that would be acceptable for the adblocker?

Comment: At any rate, *very broadly* adblockers are on a blacklist basis, so they'd only block *some* domains (or some matched patterns, e.g., "anything with `/ad/` in the URL"). Adblockers tend to avoid going the whitelist route and *only* allowing some domains. Things like uMatrix do that but that is rather...aggressive and would break a lot of sites. I'm a uMatrix user and have to adjust its settings for almost any new site I visit. In the whitelist case, almost all resources that come from a foreign domain are blocked (aside from few well known stuff like CDNs). It's possible you fall into that.

Comment: Now it occurs to me - it's possible that it's blocked because it's an HTTP request - it might be done if you're on an HTTPS domain.

Comment: @VLAZ that's a good idea but I've just tried it and it still doesn't work. Maybe it only supports certain types of certificates?

Comment: @VLAZ I've changed `localhost` to some custom name (e.g. `mydev`) through the hosts file and now it works. I still wonder what would happen in production though... I guess I'll try exploring https://github.com/brave/adblock-rust to get a better idea of what the adblocker does.